# Custom CIKernel Displacement Map

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-image, cifilter

I'm trying to create a displacement map cikernel for iOS 8 that shifts the pixels horizontally from the map R channel and vertically from the G channel.
The map pixel coordinates must be picked relative to the source image size mapPixel = ((dest.x/source.width) * map.width, (dest.y / source.height) * map.height)

The input image size that I test with is 2048 x 2048
and the map is red-green perlin noise 2560 x 2560

In Quartz Composer the cikernel works almost as expected, except that the map is not applied to the whole image

```
kernel vec4 coreImageKernel(sampler image, sampler displaceMap, float scaleX, float scaleY)
{
 vec2 destination = destCoord();

 vec2 imageSize = samplerSize(image);
 float xPercent = destination.x / imageSize.x;
 float yPercent = destination.y / imageSize.y;

 vec2 mapSize = samplerSize(displaceMap);
 vec2 mapCoord = vec2(mapSize.x * xPercent, mapSize.y * yPercent);

 vec4 mapPixel = sample(displaceMap, mapCoord);
 float ratioShiftX = ((mapPixel.x) * 2.0) - 1.0;
 float ratioShiftY = ((mapPixel.y) * 2.0) - 1.0;
 vec2 pixelShift = vec2(ratioShiftX * scaleX, ratioShiftY * scaleY);

 return sample(image, destination - pixelShift);
}
```

Here's what the filter function looks like:

```
function __image main(__image image, __image displaceMap, __number scaleX, __number scaleY) {
  return coreImageKernel.apply(image.definition, null, image, displaceMap, scaleX, scaleY);
}
```

But when I load the cikernel in CIFilter the result is far from what I see in Quartz Composer.
Here's what my apply function looks like in the CIFilter

```
override var outputImage:CIImage? {
    if let inputImage = inputImage {
        if let inputMap = inputMap {
            let args = [inputImage as AnyObject, inputMap as AnyObject, inputScaleX, inputScaleY]

            return CIDisplacementMapFilter.kernel?.applyWithExtent(inputImage.extent, roiCallback: {
                    (index, rect) in

                    if index == 0 {
                        return rect
                    }

                    return CGRectInfinite
                }, arguments: args)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

I'm guessing the ROI is wrong and the sampler is tiled, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the kernel was wrong.
Here's a kernel that does the job

```
kernel vec4 displace(sampler source, sampler map, float scaleX, float scaleY)
{

vec2 d = destCoord();
vec4 mapPixel = sample(map, samplerTransform(map, d));
float shiftX = ((mapPixel.x * 2.0) - 1.0) * scaleX;
float shiftY = ((mapPixel.y * 2.0) - 1.0) * scaleY;

vec2 s = samplerTransform(source, d + vec2(shiftX, shiftY));

return sample(source, s);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll post an answer with the code for Metal if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same code for Metal

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;
#include <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>

extern "C" {
  namespace coreimage {
    float4 displaceFilterKernel(sampler source, sampler map, float scaleX, float scaleY)
    {
      float2 d = map.coord();
      float4 mapPixel = map.sample(d);
      float shiftX = ((mapPixel.x * 2.0) - 1.0) * scaleX;
      float shiftY = ((mapPixel.y * 2.0) - 1.0) * scaleY;
      float2 s = float2(d.x, 1.0 - d.y) + float2(shiftX, shiftY);
      return sample(source, s);
    }
  }
}
```